# VBA, With worksheets and Range

Tags: excel, vba

I dont want to put the worksheet name before each of my ranges, I am trying to use `With Worksheets` to just make it cleaner, but it keeps the another sheet for my code.

Any ideas why?

```
With Worksheets("Step 4 CM")
aLastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A10:A" & aLastRow).Formula = "=$A$6"
Range("C10:C" & aLastRow).FillDown
Range("E10:E" & aLastRow).FillDown

bLastRow = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("I10:I" & bLastRow).Formula = "=$A$6"
Range("K10:K" & bLastRow).FillDown
Range("M10:M" & bLastRow).FillDown

cLastRow = .Range("S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("P10:P" & cLastRow).Formula = "=$A$6"
Range("R10:R" & cLastRow).FillDown
Range("T10:T" & cLastRow).FillDown


End With
```

Comment: If you don't put a `.` before `Range` it defaults to the active worksheet.

Comment: Which you seem to know because you have put it on the first line of each block.

Comment: I completely missed that, will close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use points in front of your subreference when using a with statement

So:

```
With Worksheets("Step 4 CM")
.Range("T10:T" & cLastRow).FillDown
End With
```

And use that on all range references.